# Youtube iFrame (with javascript API) loads the first time, but not the second one. Why?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the iFrame Youtube API with the following code. I call this view with Ajax to render it and append it in a div.yt-player within my page. It works the first time I call the view, but after I close the video (it empties the div.yt-player) and click on another link that calls my view, the video doesn't load at all (blank). I've been struggling and still don't see why it happens, especially that it works the first time. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.. Thanks.

PS: Both the html and the javascript are rendered by the view.

```
Html
<div id="player"></div>

Javascript:
var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '486',
      width: '864',
      videoId: '#{@media['youtube_url']}',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      },
      playerVars: {
        'showinfo': 0,
        'iv_load_policy': 3,
        'color': 'white',
        'fs': 1,
        'autoplay': 1,
        'vq': 'hd720'
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
```

Comment: What is the error output shown in Inspector/Firebug on the second run?

Comment: There are actually no errors logging in the console. I've just fooled around and added a call to onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() just after its declaration, and now it works all the time. Except that now I have another problem: the first time I load my page, I have to click twice to make it work. I think the reason is that the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() function is called by the YouTube API only the first time.

Comment: It does log the usual "Unable to post message to http://www.youtube.com. Recipient has origin http://127.0.0.1:3000" though (not a problem usually, and it logs it the first time too, but works anyway). I'm now reading the docs to try to find another function that I can call myself and bypass the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() the 2nd and nth time I call my view. But if you have any suggestion on how to achieve this with conditionals, I'll take it. The only restriction is that onYouTubeIframeAPIReady has to stay global and can't be nested it seems.

Comment: It might be beneficial for others to help you debug this if you set up on a http://jsfiddle.net/ sandbox. JSHint is throwing errors on this line: _videoId: '#{@media['youtube_url']}',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        },_

Comment: You're right, it's my fault. '#{@media['youtube_url']}' is rails code that is why it doesn't work. I will use jsfiddle in the future, thanks. I solved the problem btw.

Answer (score 9):

Just check if the script has been defined.

```
if(document.getElementById('iframe_api') === null){
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            tag.id = "iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        }
else
    runPlayer();

function runPlayer(){
            var player;
            player = new YT.Player(element.children()[0], {
                playerVars: {
                    autoplay: 1,
                    html5: 1,
                    controls: 1,
                    showsearch: 0,
                    showinfo: 0
                },
                height: scope.height,
                width: scope.width,
                videoId: scope.videoid,
                events: {
                    onStateChange: function (event) {
                        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                            scope.$emit('VideoEnded');
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
$window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
    runPlayer();
};
```

Comment: Perfect answer. For over 2,700 views, I can't believe this hasn't had more upvotes.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I debugged the problem. onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() is called only the first time the YouTube API is loaded (when the user refreshes the page and clicks on the link to the view for example), and because I'm calling my views in Ajax, it didn't get fired up the following times.

So I replaced the first block of code by wrapping it in a conditional:

```
  if (typeof youtube_api_init == 'undefined') {
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  }
```

and

```
if (typeof youtube_api_init != 'undefined') {
  onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
}
```

and at the end of the script, I set the youtube_api_init for the browser to remember the YouTube API has already been loaded:

```
var youtube_api_init = 1;
```

PS: the first time I tried, I called my variable yt_api_init instead of youtube_api_init, and it didn't work cause it happens that's a name YouTube already uses in its api...